# Summarize data from 1 ADE table into groups based on 2 columns

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have this data:

| Language | ID |
| --- | --- |
| English | AA |
| English | AB |
| English | AB |
| Spanish | BB |
| Spanish | CC |
| Spanish | DD |

And I want to use an ADE query to count the number of distinct ID values per Language. The output should be:

| Language | Count of IDs |
| --- | --- |
| English | 2 |
| Spanish | 3 |

How can I do this in 1 query?

Answer (score 0):

[dcount()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dcount-aggfunction) for performant approximate distinct count

```
datatable(Language:string, ID:string)
[
    "English" ,"AA"
   ,"English" ,"AB"
   ,"English" ,"AB"
   ,"Spanish" ,"BB"
   ,"Spanish" ,"CC"
   ,"Spanish" ,"DD"
]    
| summarize dcount(ID) by Language
```

| Language | dcount_ID |
| --- | --- |
| English | 2 |
| Spanish | 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUDZ/EvPTSxPRUq%20KSosy8dB0FTxcoU5OXK5qXSwEIlFzz0nMyizOUFHSUHB2VwII6KIJOeAWDCxLzoIJO2ASdnbEIurgABWNB1vNy1SgUl%20bmJhZlVqUqpCTnl%20aVaHi6aCokVSrAnA8AOI9TvtEAAAA=)

For accurate but less performant distinct count:

```
datatable(Language:string, ID:string)
[
    "English" ,"AA"
   ,"English" ,"AB"
   ,"English" ,"AB"
   ,"Spanish" ,"BB"
   ,"Spanish" ,"CC"
   ,"Spanish" ,"DD"
]    
| distinct Language, ID
| summarize count() by Language
```

| Language | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| English | 2 |
| Spanish | 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUDZ/EvPTSxPRUq%20KSosy8dB0FTxcoU5OXK5qXSwEIlFzz0nMyizOUFHSUHB2VwII6KIJOeAWDCxLzoIJO2ASdnbEIurgABWNB1vNy1SikZBaXZOYllyjA3AtyKEiiuDQ3N7EosypVITm/NK9EQ1MhqRKuCABPWPym5wAAAA==)

P.S.
We used ADX as an abbreviation for Azure Data Explorer.